# XSD: How does one make optional (sub)elements dependable?

Tags: xml, xsd, minoccurs

Let's assume working with xml documents like this:

```
<Item>
  <Price>10</Price>
  <Ratio>1.5</Ratio>
  <MaxPrice>18<MaxPrice>
</Item>
```

and

```
<Item>
  <Price>12</Price>
</Item>
```

The meaning of the data is: An *Item* must have a *price* and optionally *ratio* for iterative price change and a *maximum price* that should not be exceeded. To clarify: either only {`Price`} or all three elements {`Price`, `Ratio`, `MaxPrice`}. **No other option is allowed.**

On a regular basis, XSD allows making elements optional using `minOccurs="0"`, so we can define an `Item` like this:

```
<xs:element name="Item">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Price" type="xs:integer" />
            <xs:element name="Ratio" type="xs:float" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="MaxPrice" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

But that is not enough. This will let e.g. an `Item` with only {`Price` and `Ratio`} through - which is not correct.

How can this be done?

Comment: Unrelated comment maybe, I would suggest to never use float or double in XSDs used for financial applications; you don't want to loose pennies...

Comment: Thank  you, but the data was, indeed, just an example. The actual data describes something different, I just used an item-price example in order to avoid explaining what was the reasoning behind the data (and its semantics) I actually use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combination of `xs:sequence` and `xs:choice` is the key here, please bear in mind that the way to combine the two is significant (see below why). The correct way (at least based on what I have managed to find out) is to express build the XSD like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="itemType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Price" type="xs:integer" />
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Ratio" type="xs:float" />
                <xs:element name="MaxPrice" type="xs:integer" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="Item" type="my:itemType" />
```

That way you make the an **optional choice** to include a **fixed sequence** of elements, which is exactly what we were looking for.

(If you found what you were looking for, you can stop reading right here. What follows is merely and explanation what other approaches there seem to be and why they don't work)

One might wonder (and this was also my initial idea inspired from elsewhere) that fixed choice of two fixed sequences might work too and serve as a widely reusable pattern. As true as it may be for certain cases, this does not happen to be one of them. Observe:

```
<xs:complexType name="itemType">
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Price" type="xs:integer" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Price" type="xs:integer" />
            <xs:element name="Ratio" type="xs:float" />
            <xs:element name="MaxPrice" type="xs:integer" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="Item" type="my:itemType" />
```

Seems fine, huh? Well, apparently not - the full item would not pass through! The validator iteratively falls into the first choice, validate the `Price` element and fails stating that *following `Ratio` element is unexpected*.

Well, an obvious attempt to remedy to situation presents itself - let's switch the choices:

```
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Price" type="xs:integer" />
            <xs:element name="Ratio" type="xs:float" />
            <xs:element name="MaxPrice" type="xs:integer" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Price" type="xs:integer" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="Item" type="my:itemType" />
```

This appears to work fine, until you decide to extend the poor `Item` element (perhaps some other usage of Item element might cause trouble as well).

I have tried e.g.:

```
<xs:complexType name="DiscountedItem">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="my:itemType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Discount" type="xs:integer" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

If you try this, you'll the `DiscountedItem`s failing either with or without the {`Ratio`, `MaxPrice`} subelements depending how whether you switched the choices or not.

Nevertheless, this concludes that for this use-case it is way better to use the first mentioned "**optional choice** to include a **fixed sequence**". I found this the hard way, so you don't have to :)

Comment: You don't need the choice; keep the sequence under it, and set its minOccurs="0".

Comment: Do you mean the following?

`<xs:sequence>`
`<xs:element name="Price" type="xs:integer" />`
`<xs:sequence minOccurs="0">`
`<xs:sequence>` `<xs:element name="Ratio" type="xs:float" />`
`<xs:element name="MaxPrice" type="xs:integer" />`
`</xs:sequence>`
`</xs:sequence>`
`</xs:sequence>`

Comment: No, I mean this: 
 <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Price" type="xs:integer" />
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
            <xs:element name="Ratio" type="xs:float" />
            <xs:element name="MaxPrice" type="xs:integer" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:sequence>